# How to add data to a column in R based on if data in the same row of another column contains a character string?

Tags: r, if-statement, mutate

I am trying to add a detect Y/N column for multiple analytes in a df based on whether the result columns have a "<" symbol in the same row.

df <- data.frame( analyte1 = c( 1, 1.5, 3, <2), analyte2 = c(<1, 2, 3, <1), analyte3 = c(1, <1, 1.5, 3))

## this is what I tried, I get an error

names <-  (analyte1, analyte2, analyte3)

df <- mutate(df, across(all_of(names)), .names = 'detect_{.col}',
ifelse(grepl("<", all_of(names)), "N", "Y"))

Comment: If you have strings, you may need the `""` to create the example

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. I want to make 3 new columns (detect_analyte1, detect_analyte2, and detect_analyte3) that each have a "Y" if there is not a "<" in the corresponding row, or a "N" if there is a "<" in the corresponding row. So for detect_analyte1 it should be c("Y", "Y", "Y", N") and detect_analyte2 should be c("N", "Y", "Y", "N").

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could use:

```
cbind(df, has = grepl("<",do.call(paste, df)))

  analyte1 analyte2 analyte3   has
1        1       <1        1  TRUE
2      1.5        2       <1  TRUE
3        3        3      1.5 FALSE
4       <2       <1        3  TRUE
```

in tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(has = if_any(everything(), ~str_detect(., "<")))

  analyte1 analyte2 analyte3   has
1        1       <1        1  TRUE
2      1.5        2       <1  TRUE
3        3        3      1.5 FALSE
4       <2       <1        3  TRUE
```

## Edit:

If you need for each column:

```
cbind(df, array(!grepl("<", as.matrix(df)), dim(df)))

  analyte1 analyte2 analyte3     1     2     3
1        1       <1        1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2      1.5        2       <1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
3        3        3      1.5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
4       <2       <1        3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

in tidyverse:

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~!str_detect(., "<"), .names = "{col}_has"))

   analyte1 analyte2 analyte3 analyte1_has analyte2_has analyte3_has
1        1       <1        1         TRUE        FALSE         TRUE
2      1.5        2       <1         TRUE         TRUE        FALSE
3        3        3      1.5         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE
4       <2       <1        3        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE
```

Comment: This almost works, I need a new column for each analyte.